# If..else condition error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this following code. The code searches for value in a table and assigns mxCost. The IF..ELSE condition works for all values except 1 and is also reading the table. The IF condition makes the page crash and i am not able to figure out why? Can someone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
$jq("#airTableValues tbody tr").each(function() {
     var monthName  = months[parseInt(dateSplit[1])-1]+" "+dateSplit[0];
     if(monthName==$jq(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim())
      {
          mxCost = $jq(this).find("td:eq(6)").text().trim();
      }
  });

if (mxCost)
  mxCost = (mxCost.substring(1, mxCost.length));
else {
  mxCost = 0;
}



var MxStat = document.getElementById("MxStat").value;
MxStat = MxStat/100;
var InflationRate1 = document.getElementById("InflationRate1").value;
InflationRate1 = InflationRate1/100;

var rate3 = document.getElementById("rate3").value;
rate3 =   Math.pow(1+rate3/100,1/365)-1;
var mxAdj;
if (MxStat == 1){
   mxAdj = mxCost;
}                                         // <------- NOT WORKING!
else if (MxStat != 1) {
  var TotalCost = mxCost * 2; 
   mxAdj = (TotalCost * MxStat) - mxCost; 
}


var ReturnVal = (mxAdj * InflationRate1) + mxAdj;
var ReturnCalc = ReturnVal * 1000000;
var ReturnPV = Math.floor(ReturnCalc/Math.pow(1+rate3,periods));
document.getElementById("ReturnCondition").value = 
(ReturnPV/1000000).toFixed(2);
ReturnCondition = ReturnVal.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: in which if...else are you getting error. There are many.

Comment: @akhilaravind it's toward the bottom.  there's a "NOT WORKING" comment next to it.  I'll edit the question to make it more obvious.

Comment: `else (MxStat != 1)` is invalid syntax.  You're missing an `if`, or need to remove the condition.

Comment: @Amy Yes. I just edited it. I missed that while typing.

Comment: @Amy "ReturnVal.toFixed is not a function" is the error it's giving out when i set it to 1. But if it's not 1 then i don't get any error.

Comment: When it *isn't* 1, **what is it in actuality?**  Please be more specific on what it *is*.

Comment: @Amy It's a user input. When the input is 1, the value from the table i.e. mxCost is not being read.

Comment: `toFixed` is a number method. If you're getting `"ReturnVal.toFixed is not a function"` it means `ReturnVal` is not a number. Try parsing `ReturnVal` to a float: `parseFloat(ReturnVal).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @JosephWebber This worked for. Thank you Joseph.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
if (MxStat != 1){
  var mxAdj = (TotalCost * MxStat) - mxCost;
  var ReturnVal = (mxAdj * InflationRate1) + mxAdj;
  aReturnCondition = ReturnVal.toFixed(2);
  }
 if (MxStat == 1){
 var mxAdj =  mxCost;
var ReturnVal = (mxAdj * InflationRate1) + mxAdj;
 aReturnCondition = parseFloat(ReturnVal).toFixed(2);}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining what the problem was and *why* this fixes it, and what exactly you changed.